# Enable http requests on a https website when using content script of chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to access my unsecured server using content script, which runs on a https website. So, I got this error, is there any workaround?

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.google.com/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://my-website.com/user'. This request has been blocked; the
>   content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: The best option would be to setup HTTPS on your server. Anything else would be a hack.

Comment: i think your server is unauthorized or may be does not have a proper certificate thats why you got this error.